# Fill a RadComboBox column from xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik

Is there a way to insert items to a **RadComboBox** in a column without having to use C# code?

I have an application that displays a **Telerik RadGridView**, the first column shows the Status and I need to put a **RadComboBox** where two legends display only: "Activa" or "Cancelada" and also change the text color by changing the Status.

The color change can do in the event SelectionChanged, I do not know is do something like this but in RadComboBox column:

```
<ComboBox Height="23" Name="comboBox1" Width="120">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Activada"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Cancelada"/>
</ComboBox>
```

It has to look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do some thing like this code. just you can use gridview instead of listview

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}"  Name="listView1">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="By" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="HI">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox Name="comboBox1"  Width="60" >
                                <ComboBox.Items>
                                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Item1"/>
                                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Item2"/>
                                </ComboBox.Items>
                            </ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

and for C# code :

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<SomeData> data=new List<SomeData>();
        SomeData d=new SomeData("sara");
        data.Add(d);
        d=new SomeData("jons");
        data.Add(d);
        d=new SomeData("bil");
        data.Add(d);
        d=new SomeData("rose");
        data.Add(d);
        d=new SomeData("steve");
        data.Add(d);

        listView1.DataContext = data;
    }
}
public class SomeData
{
    public SomeData(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public string Name { set; get; }
}
```